# Окончание "е" или "и"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, окончания

Объясните, пожалуйста, правило, а также более подробно ситуацию написания:

> *Основные характеристики инженерных сетей будут изменены после подготовки технических планов и постановк**е** на государственный кадастровый учёт.*

Почему в слове *"постановк**е**"* окончание Е, а не И? В каких случаях мы пишем *постановк**и** на учёт*? Благодарю вас.

Comment: А зачем Вы пишете латинскими буквами?

Comment: "Благодарю **В**ас" неправильно писать с большой буквы, п. ч. в данном случае Вы обращаетесь ко всей аудитории, а не к конкретному человеку. Исправил ещё "буд**у**т изменены".

Answer (score 3):

В подобных случаях падежом управляет предлог. Предлог "после" здесь распространяется на *оба* слова "подготовка" и "постановка", поэтому падежные окончания в обоих словах должны быть **-И** (*родительный* падеж: после *чего*; то же было бы напр. с предлогом "без"). Окончание **-Е** в этих словах было бы в случае *предложного* падежа (без предлога - дательного, *чему*), например, с предлогом "при" (при *чём*): **при** подготовк**е**, **при** постановк**е**.

Answer (score 2):

*После постановк**е*** как раз неправильно. *После подготовки технических планов и (после) чего? постановк**и*** (родительный падеж).